# Iterate over a list in a Match query

Tags: collections, neo4j

I have a relation that has a list of ids s_ids as a property of the relation. each id in the list correspond to another node that has a sentence corresponding to an id.I used:

```
MATCH (c: term)-[r: semrel]->(t: term), (b: Sentence)
Where r.source = "xyz" And b.sentence_id IN r.s_id
return r,b
```

to return all sentences corresponding to the relation, 
the result looks like :

```
r  b
w  abc
w  rty
w  zxv
e  nmx
e  qrt
```

the relation r is repeated for every sentence how can I group the list of sentences corresponding to each relation to get

```
r  b
w  abc, rty, zxv
e  nmx,qrt
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should return each `r` and its collection of sentences:

```
MATCH (c: term)-[r: semrel]->(t: term), (b: Sentence)
WHERE r.source = "xyz" AND b.sentence_id IN r.s_i
RETURN r, COLLECT(b) AS sentences;
```

For better performance, if you create an index on :Sentence(sentence_id), like this:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Sentence(sentence_id);
```

then this query (which adds a hint to use the index) should be faster (as the `b` nodes can be found using the index):

```
MATCH (c: term)-[r: semrel]->(t: term), (b: Sentence)
USING INDEX b:Sentence(sentence_id)
WHERE r.source = "xyz" AND b.sentence_id IN r.s_i
RETURN r, COLLECT(b) AS sentences;
```